# I am unable to install Ubuntu on my partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have 2 hard disks - an SSD and normal HDD.

My Windows 7 is installed on the SSD.
I have created 40 gb of unallocated space on the HDD for installing Ubuntu.

While installing the Ubuntu installer does not detect the HDD drive even though its mounted. I went to the advanced partition tool and it could not find any partitions. It simply says 1 TB HDD and I cannot do anything more.

They are dynamic partitions. But I cannot access the unallocated 40 GB.

Comment: Are you sure that both the hard disks have the same type of partition table? either RAID or MBR? In which mode are you installing Ubuntu? UEFI or BIOS?

Comment: No both the hard disks don't have the same partition table.